# Custom linked list with too much items crashes while passing through. C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm learning programming and I've wanted to make some basic data structures. I tried to search over here but I didn't find any solution (ok, neither similiar problem). Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Data
{
public:
  Data(int value):thatValue(value) {}
  ~Data(){}
  void Show() {cout << thatValue << "\n";}
private:
  int thatValue;
};

class Node
{
public:
  Node(Data * pData, Node * Next);
  ~Node() {delete thatData; thatData=0; delete thatNext; thatNext=0;}
  void ShowData() {thatData->Show();}
  void ShowNext() {if(thatNext != 0) { thatNext->ShowData(); thatNext->ShowNext();}}

private:
  Data * thatData;
  Node * thatNext;
};

Node::Node(Data * pData, Node * Next)
{
  thatData = pData;
  thatNext = Next;
}

class LinkedList
{
public:
  LinkedList(int size);
  ~LinkedList() {delete thatNext; thatNext=0; delete thatData; thatData=0;}
  void Insert(Data * newData);
  void PrintAll();

private:
  Node * thatNext;
  Data * thatData;
};

LinkedList::LinkedList(int size)
{
  thatNext = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    {
      thatData = new Data(i);
      Insert(thatData);
    }
}
void LinkedList::Insert(Data * newData)
{
  Node * pNode = new Node(newData, thatNext);
  thatNext = pNode;
}
void LinkedList::PrintAll()
{
  thatNext->ShowData();
  thatNext->ShowNext();
}

int main ()
{
  LinkedList * LS = new LinkedList(100000);
  LS->PrintAll();
  delete LS;
  return 0;
}
```

So the problem is, that when the linked list is small enough (<50000 items), then the program execute as i expected. But when it has more items, it crashes, while it is executing function `LinkedList::PrintAll()`.
I'm sorry if the problem is something stupid or obvious, or if the impletation is completely wrong. But I cannot see the problem.

Comment: do you get any error messages on crash?

Comment: Do you know what StackOverflow is?

Comment: There should be a badge for first questions that unknowingly involve a stack overflow.

Comment: @Jan You are not freeing all the nodes correctly. There are memory leaks in the program ;)

Comment: @Mahesh Yes, i didn't make correct destructors. I've stuckt on this. But thank you.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Yes that's the problem. I do not. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get a stack overflow. Why do you do it recursively? Just make a simple loop.

```
void LinkedList::PrintAll()
{
  thatNext->ShowData();
  Node* thatOtherNext;
  while (thatOtherNext = thatNext->thatNext)
     thatOtherNext->ShowData();
}
```

or something similar...

Comment: Thank you.. I have to study what's going to stack. Atleast I'm starting to know why i shouldn't use recurse on something.

Answer (score 1):

You call  `LS->PrintAll();`

```
void LinkedList::PrintAll()
{
  thatNext->ShowData();
  thatNext->ShowNext();
}
```

which calls `thatNext->ShowNext();`

```
void ShowNext() {if(thatNext != 0) { 
    thatNext->ShowData(); thatNext->ShowNext();}
}
```

which calls `thatNext->ShowNext();` again, recursively

Each call puts the variable `this` (plus some other stuff) on the stack.  The stack is only so big, so the Stack Overflows.  For lists this big, you'll have to print the list iteratively instead of recursively.

```
void LinkedList::PrintAll()
{
     Node* cur = thatNext;
     while thatNext points to a Node
          Show cur's data
          make cur point to cur's next node
     done
}
```

This way it doesn't overflow the stack (it's also faster)